# Creating an .app file using Platypus failing with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import os
import subprocess

pathName = "FilePath"
os.chdir(r'Directory Path')
process = subprocess.Popen(["scrapy", "crawl", "homeDepotSpider", "-t" , "csv"  , "-o", pathName])
```

Here's the error message I get:

```
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__ errread, errwrite) File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can't really find any documentation online, but is Platypus just not compatible with subprocess or is there something wrong with my code. When I compile it runs fine, when I create an .app file it doesnt work.

Edit: Here is the software that I used to make my program into an executable: https://sveinbjorn.org/platypus

Comment: How is this code creating a file? And the [tag:platypus] tag says it's an "object-oriented layout engine for ReportLab". What does that have to do with your question? The code and the description seem entirely unrelated. Also, what does "when I compile it runs fine" mean? Python isn't a compiled language. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris Sorry! I'll update my post, Platypus is an application I downloaded that allows me to convert my python files into executables. I'll edit my post with the link to platypus/remove the platypus tag

Answer (score 0):

The Exception says the reason: "No such file"

What `subprocess.Popen`  line is trying to do is roughly the same as running `scrapy` in a cmd prompt.  That is (in Windows terms), in the PATH of the subprocess you are trying to launch there is no folder containing 'scrapy.exe' .

I read that you used some packaging SW to bundle your script. The packaging program has not packaged the `scrapy` executable.

Comment: That does make sense! So the solution would be to copy the scrapy executable into that file path?

Comment: You have to make sure that when the script is running, the `sys.path` has a folder which has `scapy` executable. You might be able to check if it is working correctly by logging the sys.path. I haven't used this Platypus, but in the [documentation](https://sveinbjorn.org/files/manpages/PlatypusDocumentation.html) it mentions also some ways to make the script to access user's environment (and PATH). Third option would be to try to include the `scrapy` executable somehow into the package you are creating which Platypus.